# Angular 5 translate i18n without ngx-translate

Tags: angular, internationalization, translation, angular5

Since one of the devs at Angular wrote [this](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/495#issuecomment-325570932):

> It won't be for 5.0, it should be before 6.0 (so before march 2018). Unfortunately I don't have a more precise date

I was wondering how to proceed with my Angular 5 app which I want to offer in two languages. The user should have the opportunity to switch the languages with a button.
I read that for now you can only do that with ngx-translate, but since I would like to use the soon built in feature of Angular, I would like to program it in a way so I dont have to do the work twice!

In worst case I will offer the page only in one language until this feature gets released.

So is there a way yet to offer the app in more then just one language and let the user simply switch between them only with the i18n included in Angular?

Comment: There is no question in your post. In the meantime you can read this : https://dzone.com/articles/angular-localization-and-internationalization

Comment: The quote you linked to isn't about being able to change the language. It's about being able to translate text in the code, and not just in the template. Even in 6.0, you probably won't be able to change the language, except by reloading a different version of the application, translated in another language. And you can already do that now.

Comment: But didnt the developer say ngx will be depricated after angular 6 since they will implement everything thats missing?
I didnt quite get how to use the two versions of this app with different languages. Is there some tutorial for that i missed?

Comment: @x2twelve you have myapp.fr, myapp.com and myapp.es, and when you change the language from English to French, you simply navigate from myapp.com to myapp.fr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now if you do not want to use ngx-translate there is no way to dynamically translate your application. If you use Angular's i18n spec you can build two different versions in your production build. One with 'en' for English and one with 'es' for Spanish for example (Two different folders in your server). The problem is the whole application will reload when you change the locale. The pros are that this method is easy to use since you have to have the 'i18n' directive in places where the language need to be translated and write the language specific variables in separate config files (xlf). For example:

`<h1 i18n>Hello i18n!</h1>`

Comment: thanks!
I already managed to generate the xlf files and run/build it with different languages. But did I understand it right, that Angular will support dynamic translation soon? If so I will stick with this solution, if you only could point me out how to implement that? Should I just link to the different app which is in the folder `en_US` for example? So i wont be able easily to transfer data between those two apps right? Or is there a more elegant solution?

thank you very much so far!

Comment: You have understood correctly, however we don't know if the Angular team sees this as a priority. If you link to different apps you will loose some of the application state. So if you are planning to that that route make sure the current state of the application can be retrieved from the backend/ database, otherwise you might have to get your hand dirty and use local storage.